# Permutations of word 'mathematics'

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many arrangements are there of MATHEMATICS with both T's before both A's or both A's before both M's or both M's before the E ?

Can someone also point to some online resource that has such practice questions ?

Thanks.

**Edit**:

I have some initial thought, please tell me if I am in the right direction :

For the case both T's before both A's :

We can picture the permutation as follows :

(7) T (7) T (7) A (7) A (7)  (Remaining letters: M H E M I C S - total 7)

Each of the brackets are empty spaces for now. We need to pick 7 out of the total 7 X 5 = 35 spaces; that will ensure both T's being before both A's.

So number of ways = C(35,7) X 7!/2! (because two M's are same - we need to divide by 2!)

Comment: By the inclusion-exclusion principle, the answer would be
[# of arrangements with both Ts before both As]
+ [# of arrangements with both As before both Ms]
+ [# of arrangements with both Ms before E]
- [# of arrangements with both Ts before both As AND both As before both Ms]
- [# of arrangements of both As before both Ms AND both Ms before E]
- [# of arrangements of both Ts before both As AND both Ms before E]
+ [# of arrangements of both Ts before As AND both As before Ms AND both Ms before E].
I'll leave the rest for you to figure out.

Comment: @2012ssohn I have made an edit

Comment: @dfeuer I have made an edit

Comment: Dear moderators, cut the bullying and please activate this question. The whole world wouldn't turn upside down if one or two questions lacking info are active.

Comment: @AJR Can you please tell me my thinking in the question is in the right direction ?

Comment: @Jake Yes, you are heading in the right direction. Try to use http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php for LaTex formatting.

Comment: @AJR, when you reach a sufficient reputation score you will be able to vote to reopen questions (or not to close them). In the mean time, it seems the admonishment was effective in this case, the OP wrote down some thoughts, the question was reopened, and Barry Cipra gave an answer. That is, the system worked this time, for the benefit of all involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were headed in the right direction, but you went way too far.  The $C(35,7)$ is much too much.  It counts, for example, "-M---I-T..." and "--M-I--T..." as different, even though both are basically "MIT..."

Here's a way to think of it.  Starting from TTAA, allow yourself to insert the other letters, C, E, H, I, M, M, and S, one at a time, anywhere before, between, or after letters already in position.  (It might help to picture the second M as, temporarily, an N, remembering to divide by $2$ when you're done.)  The C have $5$ places it can go, the E then has $6$, the H has $7$, and so forth, for a total of

$$(5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\cdot11)/2$$

Can you now do the other examples you asked about (both A's before both M's or both M's before the E)?  The first of those should actually be very easy!

Comment: So in that case .. T's before A's and A's before M's would have the same answer, for M's before the E ... the answer would be = (4x5x6x7x8x9x10x11) / (2x2) .. correct ?

Comment: @Jake, sounds right to me.

Answer (score 0):

First the seven letters _M_H_E_M_I_C_S_ can be arranged among themselves in $7!/2!$ ways.
Then we are left with $8$ places in between, infront or at the end of word.
Now we have to Insert two A's at the last $6$ gaps this can be done in $C(6,2)/2!$ ways.  After filling in these gaps we are left with $6$ gaps which can be filled by remaining two T's in $C(6,2)/2!$ ways.
Hence the required number of ways  is $$\frac{7! \cdot C(6,2) \cdot C(6,2)}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}$$ 
Hope you understand this.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since you can place two A's or two T's in the same gap.

Answer (score 0):

A particular permutation of the letters of the word MATHEMATICS is determined by choosing which two of the eleven places will be filled with M's, then choosing which two of the remaining nine places will be filled with A's, then choosing which two of the remaining seven places will be filled with T's, and finally permuting the five remaining letters.  Therefore, the number of permutations of the letters of the word MATHEMATICS is 
$$\binom{11}{2}\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{2} \cdot 5! = \frac{11!}{9!2!} \cdot \frac{9!}{7!2!} \cdot \frac{7!}{5!2!} \cdot 5! = \frac{11!}{2!2!2!}$$ 
There are 
$$\binom{4}{2} = 6$$
permutations of the letters AATT since a particular permutation is determined by selecting which two of the four places will be filled with A's.  Of these six permutations, only one (TTAA) has both T's before both A's.  Thus, the number of permutations of MATHEMATICS in which both T's appear before both A's is 
$$\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{11!}{2!2!2!}$$

Answer (score 0):

I tried : Let A,B,C are sets  respectively  in which arrangement of MATHEMATICS in which both T's before both both A's ,both A's before both M's ,both M's before the E.  Now we solve this problem by using set theorotical formula  :-   |A union B union C|= {|A|+|B|+|C|} - {|A intersection B| +|B intersection C|+|A intersection C|} + { |A intersection B  intersection C |}  So the answer is : {C(11,4)×7!/2! + C(11,4)×7!/2! + C(11,3)×8!/2!2!} - { C(11,6)×5!+ C(11,5)× 6!/2!+ C(11,4)×C(7,3)×4! } + { C(11,7)×4! }

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).